# Making a bar graph using geom_bar, y scale does not match data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im working with the MPG data set. I am trying to make a bar graph with cylinders  (cyl) on the X axis and Highway miles per gallon (hwy) on the y- axis using the code below.

```
ggplot(data= mpg) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x =cyl, y= hwy), stat = "identity")
```

The Y- values for Hwy in the data set are between ~20-30 mpg, but on my graph the y-axis values range from 0-2000.

Why are the Y- values different in the graph?

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the lack of another variable. You got large values because all quantities are accumulating. If you add a variable like this, you will get what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
ggplot(data= mpg,aes(x =factor(cyl), y= hwy,fill=manufacturer)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Output:

[image]

Where values for `hwy` are now displayed properly:

```
#Code
summary(mpg$hwy)
```

Output:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  12.00   18.00   24.00   23.44   27.00   44.00
```

One option to keep only two variables and analysing their relationship is using `geom_point()` in this way:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(data= mpg,aes(x =cyl, y= hwy)) +
  geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Frcarran Great! It depends on you how to design the plot :) If you think this answer was useful you could acept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer or you could upvote. It is up to you :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! The issue appears to be accumulated values. Is there a way to fix it with out adding another variable. I need a graph with just those two variables to examine the relationship between them

Comment: @Frcarran It is possible, I will add an update now! What you want is that the y axis variable `hwy` must be between real values, right?

Comment: @Frcarran I have added an update using a different geom that keeps only the two variables! Let me know if that works for you!